# WPF ScrollViewer not activating on Window Resize

Tags: wpf, xaml

This may have been asked, but wasn't able to find the exact question.

Basically I have a WPF Window that I use as a Form. Now for the form, I have a StackPanel that helps keep all the controls and labels in place.

If the user has a smaller resolution display, the window size will be slower so for example 800x600. Some controls get lost.

For this I have added a ScrollViewer wrapped around the StackPanel. But the ScrollViewer never activates. Its probably got something to do with the stackpanel never being limited I suppose. But how can I activate the scroll viewer if the user resizes the window, or the window (when it opens) cannot display all contents properly?

I don't think its necesary to put my xaml here, but if you need it let me know. thanks!

Comment: Need `Xaml` as it is the key to the story.. :D

Answer (score 4):

A `StackPanel` has infinite size (doesn't respect its parent bounds) so you should wrap it in a `Grid`, which in turn is inside the `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: Hi Dean, I have tried that. The only problem is that when a user takes the window to fullscreen mode, the grid fixes itself. What I am looking for is something flexible that can show me everything if the window space allows and if there isn't room, to show a scroll bar allowing the user to view nonvisible controls.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
  <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer1">
   <DataGrid Name="dgDataList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="View" IsReadOnly="True">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  //control like textblock, image etc
                </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>                                    
    </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer2" >
 <DataGrid Name="dgDataList2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="View" IsReadOnly="True">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  //control like textblock, image etc
                </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>                                    
    </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I tried this, but you're taking a slightly diff approach, your adding multiple scroll bars. Isn't there any way to initialize the scrollview if the control cannot fit all its child elements. something very similar a ListView. If the listview becomes taller than its children, the scrollbar disapears. If not it appears!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem where the horizontal scrollbar wasn't being displayed even though there was content on the screen that was hidden.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestingPlatform.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" 
        Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel Width="1248" Height="600">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right">Right</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Set the window to have the size you would like for your window. Also set the Stackpanel size so it neatly fits all of your content.

The window size isn't as important as setting the StackPanel height/width otherwise the StackPanel will inherit it's size from the window.

You can resize this window and the scrollbars will appear/disappear (if `ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"` is set). If you do not set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`, the scrollviewer will not display the horizontal scrollbar regardless of the content size.